# How to set the value of the original field with django modeltranslation?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I've been adding German model translations using [django-modeltranslation](https://django-modeltranslation.readthedocs.io/) and I found out that I've accidentally set the original field values (that are supposed to be in English) to German. So now in the database I have:

- `name`: German value (should be English)
- `name_en`: English (correct)
- `name_de`: German (correct)

Is there a way to copy over the `name_en` values to `name` either in Python or directly in PostgreSQL? I've read the [access/read rules](https://django-modeltranslation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#rules-for-translated-field-access) but I'm not 100% sure how they impact what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution to fix it without going to the DB level.

```
from django.utils.translation import activate


activate('en')

for x in Model.objects.all():
    setattr(x, 'name', x.name)
    x.save()
```